# warning MSB3270: mismatch between the processor architecture of the project

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I am building a project which is showing a warning:

> warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project
> being built "AMD64" and the processor architecture of the reference
> "DiagLib, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=x86", "x86".
> This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture of
> your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures between your project
> and references, or take a dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted
> processor architecture of your project.

My project is working fine but I would like to remove this warning.

Comment: Did you try changing the targeted processor as suggested in your warning message ?

Comment: Hi.. Ya the targeted processor is always set to x64 only. I verified that in Configuration Manager. Any way to solve this warning? Please help.. Thanks..

Comment: In your warning message, the `processorArchitecture` is x86. Have you tried changing your targeted processor to x86 ?

Comment: I've this also with VS-2017 and compiling a compound C# C++ C project in 32-bits (x86, C-part unmanaged). It is the last warning.. and I cant solve it :( nothing goes wrong, everything runs fine.

Comment: Found it.. I solved the warning by setting the top level program (C#) from target "Any CPU" to target "x86" in Project Properties. This is strange, because Microsoft promises a valid link from "Any CPU" to x86 CPP/CLI wrappers.

Answer (score 12):

See comment above.

The warning occurs for C# parts of your x64 program. It is probably set to "Any CPU" because your application is running fine.

For compound C#/C++ projects, better avoid "Any CPU" in the C# part. Make sure you set "x64" explicitly as Platform Target on all C# components and also "x64" for the current mode of your solution.

Comment: Thanks, that was my problem. It solved my "Could not copy the file ..\singlefilehost.exe because it was not found." too